# One Windows 2008 R2 server can't connect to samba share, others can

Tags: windows, samba

Hi I have the following Samba configuration

```
[root@PCP66STORAGE04 log]# testparm
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
WARNING: The "null passwords" option is deprecated
Processing section "[public]"
Processing section "[data]"
Processing section "[recstore66]"
WARNING: The security=share option is deprecated
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

[global]
        server string = Data Centre Server Version %v
        security = SHARE
        null passwords = Yes
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 50
        preferred master = Yes
        default service = global
        winbind use default domain = Yes
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        path = /var/local/public
        read only = No
        guest ok = Yes
        cups options = raw

[public]
        comment = Public Stuff
        create mask = 0755

[data]
        path = /var/local/data

[recstore66]
        comment = recstore66
        path = /var/local/samba/recstore66
[root@PCP66STORAGE04 log]#
```

One of my windows 2008 servers can not browse the Samba recstore66 share, but others can do this just fine. The server that can not connect is on the same subnet, has same gateway etc. They can ping each other.
Not sure what's going on here, can you please point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Windows server was using SMB2.

running

```
To disable SMBv2 and SMBv3 on the SMB client, run the following commands:
sc.exe config lanmanworkstation depend= bowser/mrxsmb10/nsi 
sc.exe config mrxsmb20 start= disabled
```

fixed it :D